Modding with Unity BepinEX: Cannot do BasePlugin.AddComponent even if my class inherits from MonoBehaviour
First, I won't even consider myself a "new comer" to Unity Modding. I am just playing with things and trying to make some sense out of them.
I came across a Sons of the Forest mod here and seems like its no longer supported and buggy so I decided to temper with it a little bit to see what's going on.
I'm having error message when the code trying to do BasePlugin.AddComponent<TrajectoryManager>(). The error message is esoteric to me...

The type 'BowTrajectory.TrajectoryManager' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'BasePlugin.AddComponent<T>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'BowTrajectory.TrajectoryManager' to 'Il2CppInterop.Runtime.InteropTypes.Il2CppObjectBase'.

According to the documentation of BasePlugin.AddComponent, the type argument should be like something that inherits from MonoBehaviour, which is exactly what's happening in this piece of code.
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using BepInEx;
using Mache;
using BepInEx.Unity.IL2CPP;
using UnityEngine;
using Mache.Utils;
using Sons.Weapon;
using TheForest.Utils;
using static Ballistics.BulletHandler;
using Mache.UI;
using BepInEx.Configuration;

namespace BowTrajectory
{
    [BepInDependency("com.willis.sotf.mache")]
    [BepInPlugin(ModId, ModName, Version)]
    [BepInProcess("SonsOfTheForest.exe")]
    public class Plugin : BasePlugin
    {
        public const string ModId = "com.willis.sotf.bowtrajectory";
        public const string ModName = "Bow Trajectory";
        public const string Version = "1.0.0";

        internal static Plugin Instance { get; private set; }

        public override void Load()
        {
            Instance = this;
            AddComponent<TrajectoryManager>(); // Error Here
        }
    }

    public class TrajectoryManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private ConfigEntry<bool>? craftedBowEnabled, tacticalBowEnabled, crossbowEnabled;
        private LineRenderer? _trajectoryLine;
        private LineRenderer TrajectoryLine
        {
            get
            {
                if (_trajectoryLine == null)
                {
                    var pluginDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                    var bundlePath = Path.Combine(pluginDir, "StreamingAssets", "willis", "bowtrajectory");
                    var bundle = UniverseLib.AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(bundlePath);
                    _trajectoryLine = Instantiate(bundle.LoadAsset<GameObject>("Trajectory Line")).GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
                    DontDestroyOnLoad(_trajectoryLine.gameObject);
                    _trajectoryLine.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                }
                return _trajectoryLine;
            }
        }

        private bool IsLineInitialized
        {
            get => _trajectoryLine != null;
        }

        private void Awake()
        {
            craftedBowEnabled = Plugin.Instance.Config.Bind(Plugin.ModId, "CraftedBowEnabled", true, "Trajectory enabled for Crafted Bow?");
            tacticalBowEnabled = Plugin.Instance.Config.Bind(Plugin.ModId, "TacticalBowEnabled", true, "Trajectory enabled for Tactical Bow?");
            crossbowEnabled = Plugin.Instance.Config.Bind(Plugin.ModId, "CrossbowEnabled", true, "Trajectory enabled for Crossbow?");
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            Mache.Mache.RegisterMod(() => new ModDetails
            {
                Id = Plugin.ModId,
                Name = Plugin.ModName,
                Description = "Renders a line when drawing your bow indicating the expected trajectory of your arrows.",
                OnFinishedCreating = CreateMenu
            });
        }

        private void CreateMenu(GameObject parent)
        {
            var craftedBowToggle = new ToggleComponent
            {
                Title = "Crafted Bow Trajectory Enabled?",
                OnValueChanged = (self, val) => craftedBowEnabled.Value = val
            };
            var tacticalBowToggle = new ToggleComponent
            {
                Title = "Tactical Bow Trajectory Enabled?",
                OnValueChanged = (self, val) => tacticalBowEnabled.Value = val
            };
            var crossbowToggle = new ToggleComponent
            {
                Title = "Crossbow Trajectory Enabled?",
                OnValueChanged = (self, val) => crossbowEnabled.Value = val
            };

            MenuPanel.Builder()
                .AddComponent(craftedBowToggle)
                .AddComponent(tacticalBowToggle)
                .AddComponent(crossbowToggle)
                .BuildToTarget(parent);
        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            if (!LocalPlayer.IsInWorld || LocalPlayer.Inventory.RightHandItem == null)
            {
                if (IsLineInitialized)
                {
                    TrajectoryLine.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                }
                return;
            }

            var item = LocalPlayer.Inventory.RightHandItem;
            var ranged = item.ItemObject.GetComponentInChildren<RangedWeapon>();
            var controller = item.ItemObject.GetComponentInChildren<BowWeaponController>();

            if (ranged == null || controller == null || !EnabledForItem(item.Data.Id))
            {
                TrajectoryLine.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                return;
            }

            if (controller.isActiveAndEnabled)
            {
                TrajectoryLine.gameObject.SetActive(true);

                ranged.bulletInfo = ranged.GetAmmo()._properties.ProjectileInfo;
                TrajectoryData trajectory = ranged.SimulateTrajectory();
                TrajectoryLine.SetVertexCount(trajectory.arcPoints.Count);
                for (int i = 0; i < trajectory.arcPoints.Count; i++)
                {
                    TrajectoryLine.SetPosition(i, trajectory.arcPoints[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TrajectoryLine.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

        private bool EnabledForItem(int itemID)
        {
            if (itemID == GameItem.CraftedBow.GetId() && craftedBowEnabled.Value)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (itemID == GameItem.TacticalBow.GetId() && tacticalBowEnabled.Value)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (itemID == GameItem.Crossbow.GetId() && crossbowEnabled.Value)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}

I looked up some documentation and searched the problem. Did not find an answer.
I'm expecting the code to compile and test it in the game. Now the code won't compile because of the error.
